# Painting textures with 3d brush - stretching issue

Tags: texturing

Just getting started with Blender, and have been painting textures onto my model.

I set the texture brush as 3d, and painted all the top faces no issue. However when I paint faces side facing, the texture 'stretches', like this:

[image]

I've looked through all the brush settings and can't see anything obvious that will stop this. Can someone tell me the fix?

I'm using the 3d brush because I don't want the size of my painted texture differing by zooming in/out

Comment: are you sure it has nothing to do with your unwrap?

Comment: Try adding a seam to the ledge where the non-stretched and the stretched version of the texture meet, and then unwrap again.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to fix it :(

Comment: you need to check your uv map and make sure these faces are correctky unwrapped

Comment: I created a basic cube from scratch in a new project, unwrapped it, and the same texture issue happens on that too. I googled it and apparently its a thing with brushes set as '3D', and you need to set up texture nodes or something to work around it. Just looking into that now...

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic. Thanks.